# Can we configure error reporting in GCP using P99/P95 methodology

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We just configuring error reporting in GCP which shows the histogram of errors (group by type) over time. But i think this data isn't that useful. I mean, for sake of argument, having 100 errors for 100 requests means that our service is broken. but 100 errors for 1,000,000 request is okayish.

thats why i was thinking to add alerts/monitoring using P99/P95/P90 methods. I would also like to see if we can configure alerts based on # of data points i.e., if error count on P90 > 5 for 10 minutes, then alert.

Is it something that can be done in GCP? I believe this is possible in AWS but not in GCP.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Stackdriver Monitoring and Alerting for this. [Here's](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quickstart-lamp) a quickstart to help you get this set up.